# Join domain name and permalink in to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have model looks like this :

```
class Listdomain < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :domainname, :permalink
   before_create :make_it_permalink

   validates_presence_of :domainname

   private
      def make_it_permalink
       self.permalink = SecureRandom.base64(8)
      end
end
```

Try to join id and permalink on params `localhost:3000/1-oKPgT0s0S+U=` and it's works

```
 #routes.rb
 match ':id' => 'homes#whoisresult', :as => :whois

 #controller
 def whoisresult
   @listdomain = Listdomain.find(params[:id])
   @domaintld = @listdomain.domainname
 end

 #model
 def to_param
   [id, permalink].join("-")
 end
```

Try to use domainname on params `localhost:3000/domainuser.com` and it's works

```
 #routes.rb
 match ':domainname' => 'homes#whoisresult', :as => :whois, :constraints => { :domainname => /[^\/]+/ }

 #controller
 def whoisresult
   @listdomain = Listdomain.find_by_domainname(params[:domainname])
   @domaintld = @listdomain.domainname
 end
```

I want join domain name and permalink using to_param like this :

`localhost:3000/permalink-domainname`

permalink : `oKPgT0s0S+U=`

domainame : `domainuser.com`

join with `-`

```
  #routes.rb
  match ':permalink' => 'homes#whoisresult', :as => :whois, :constraints => { :permalink => /[^\/]+/ }

  #controller
  def whoisresult
    @listdomain = Listdomain.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    @domaintld = @listdomain.domainname # line 34
  end

  #model
  def to_param
    [permalink, domainname.downcase].join("-")
  end
```

And I tried get => `localhost:3000/oKPgT0s0S+U=-domainuser.com`

I got an error message like this

```
undefined method `domainname' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:34:in `whoisresult'
```

How can I join domain name and permalink on to_param ?

Comment: So, `@listdomain = Listdomain.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])` isn't finding a Listdomain. Figure that out.

Comment: But when try using only permalink on params without join domainname, and get `localhost:3000/oKPgT0s0S+U=` it's works

Answer (score 0):

```
@listdomain = Listdomain.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
```

Is returning an empty result. So check `params[:permalink]` to make sure you are passing the right permalink, as well check to see if you have a `Listdomain` in your database with that permalink.

Comment: yes, I have permalink on my database, when try using only permalink on params without join with domainname, and get `localhost:3000/oKPgT0s0S+U=` it's works